# LISP - Calculate dynamic iterator before loop without let

Tags: loops, lisp

I want to write a function that is analogous to mapcar, but it maps a function over a range of numbers instead. The function must iterate from start up to or down to end, depending on which is larger. Yes, this is for a class, but I am not looking for code, just a hint on how to accomplish this. I was informed to calculate the iterator first, but without using let. Is there another, more efficient way to declare and use a local variable other than using let? Here is my code:

```
(defun mapnum (fun start end)
  (cond
   ((< start end)
    (loop for x from start to (- end 1)
       collect  (funcall fun x)))
   ((> start end)
    (loop for x from start downto (+ end 1)
       collect  (funcall fun x)))
   (t nil)))
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make use of the signum function to know if I should increment or decrement.

```
(defun mapnum (func start end)
    (do ((i start)
        (j end (+ j (signum (- start end))))
        (res nil))
    ((equal i j) res)
    (setf res (cons (funcall func j) res))))
```

EDIT: modified the code to avoid appending to the end of the list.

Comment: appending to the end of a list is bad.